# How to use childwindow in this case

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

I am working on a silverlight 5 existing application where MVVM approached is followed.

I have created a my own ErrorMessageBox.xaml (childwindow) in View folder and i am in situation where this ErrorMessageBox must be popuped in a class inside Model folder.

And i found that the ErrorMessageBox are not accessible in Model (because it is in View folder).So at last i created one more ErrorMessageBox.xaml inside Model so that it will be used in all 
classes in Model folder.

And when i try to popup this child window(ErrorMessageBox.xaml) then it do not pop up. Why it happens and how to Pop up this ErrorMessageBox.xaml inside a function call in a class in Model
folder.

```
public static void ThisFunctionIsCalledIHaveVerifiedOnDebugging(string message)  //it is inside a class in Model folder
{
    ConfirmationWindow cfw = new ConfirmationWindow();
    cfw.SetMessage("Popup test");
    cfw.Show(); //it do not pop up it
}
```

And ConfirmationWindow.xaml is :

```
<silvercontrols:ChildWindow x:Class="Model.MessageFolder.ConfirmationWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:silvercontrols="clr-namespace:Silverlight.Windows.Controls;assembly=Silverlight.Windows.Controls"
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
          xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
           Title="Message" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MouseRightButtonDown="ChildWindow_MouseRightButtonDown">

    <silvercontrols:ChildWindow.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MessageBoxStyle"/>
    </silvercontrols:ChildWindow.Style>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" MinWidth="360">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="MessageBox" Margin="10 15 0 0" Height="Auto" FontSize="12" Text="Text" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <StackPanel x:Name="ContentBox" Margin="10 15 0 0" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="45">
                <Button x:Name="YesBtn" Content="Yes" Width="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle_Blue}"/>
                <Button x:Name="NoBtn" Content="No" Margin="60 0 0 0" Width="82" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle_Blue}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</silvercontrols:ChildWindow>
```

and ConfirmationWindow.xaml.cs is :

```
using System.Windows;   
namespace Model.MessageFolder
{
    public partial class ConfirmationWindow : Silverlight.Windows.Controls.ChildWindow
    {
        private bool showBtnClose;
        public ConfirmationWindow(bool showBtnClose = false)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HasCloseButton = showBtnClose;
            this.showBtnClose = showBtnClose;
            NoBtn.Click += Close;
        }

        #region METHODS
        public void SetMessage(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Text = message;
        }
        public void AddContent(UIElement elt)
        {
            ContentBox.Children.Add(elt);
        }
        #endregion

        #region EVENT_HANDLER
        public void Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        #endregion

        private void ChildWindow_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Why it is not working? How to make it work ?

Comment: have you tried with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() and also try to bring the CFW to front using istopmost=true

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you should not bring your childwindow class in the models folder because it breaks the MVVM pattern. Instead leave it in your views folder.
What you should do is to show the childwindow from your model's view.
To achieve that you need a way to tell your view when to show the childwindow and what message it should display.

First, in your model create a property ErrorMessage:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

{
...

```
private string _errorMessage;
public string ErrorMessage
    {
        private set
        {
            _errorMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
        }
        get { return _errorMessage;; }
    }
```

...
}

Note: I assume here that your model class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface but it could be a different implementation.

Then in your view's code behind add a dependency property and bind it to your model's ErrorMessage.
The dependency property's change callback is used to display the childwindow.
This could look like the following:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
```

{
...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorMessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ErrorMessage", typeof (string), typeof (MyView),
                 new PropertyMetadata((o, args) =>
                 {
                    // Display childwindow when message is changed
                    string message = args.NewValue as string;
                    if(message!=null)
                    {
                            ConfirmationWindow cfw = new ConfirmationWindow();
                            cfw.SetMessage(message);
                            cfw.Show(); 
                    }
                 }));

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ErrorMessageProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value); }
    }
```

...

```
public MyModel ViewModel
    {
...
        set
        {
            DataContext = value;                

            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = value;
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ErrorMessage");
            SetBinding(ErrorMessageProperty, binding);
        }
     ...
    }
```

...
}

Then every time you change the value of ErrorMessage in your model it should show the childwindow.